# Run Time Error When Moving Chart (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am creating a macro that will automatically graph a lot of data for me. I would like it to put four graphs per page, but am having an issue moving the graphs to a blank chart sheet. The charts are XYScatter charts.

I am using this command to move them, where Vars(iOrg, 3) contains the name of the blank chart sheet:

```
.Location xlLocationAsObject, Vars(iOrg, 3)
```

This command actually works and moves the chart like it is supposed to, but I then get a run time error:

```
Run-time error '1004':

The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type.
```

If i hit 'debug' and just skip over the line, the command has no problems on the next three charts, only the first one.

I recorded a marco while manually moving the chart, it will produce the same message if I actually try to use it. Although it too will actually move the chart.

```
Sub Macro6()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Control"
End Sub
```

Any idea what might be causing this error and how to avoid it? I can't recall ever having a code do what it was supposed to, then produce an error before.

Also it doesn't seem to have an issue moving the chart to a worksheet, only a blank chart sheet.

FYI: Chart Type is xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers, Excel 2013.

Comment: Can't repro with a simple scatter chart. Is there something different about that one chart?

Comment: It is a xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers chart

Comment: Unfortunately still no repro. Any chance you could add a screenshot of a sample chart?

Comment: The fix here for 2016 worked for me;  http://kb.palisade.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=1118   Initially I saw the same error you listed, but after following the steps it did not re-occur.

Comment: Can you just create the chart on the new worksheet, without using an intermediate chart sheet?

Comment: @JonPeltier that would be preferred option, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

Comment: How are you creating the chart? Got code?

Comment: Add a chart directly to the active worksheet: `ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart` or `ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2`. Look up the syntax in the Object Browser.